# Link in webpage to local file

Tags: firefox, html, links

I made a webpage in apache server, and added the link `<a href="file:///home/user/page.html>Link</a>`. This does not work. Why, and is there a way to make it work? If instead i added that link to a `.html` file and opened it directly (not throught server), the link would work.

Comment: Who's web page? What website?

Comment: @DavidPostill Mine. I have an apache server and added that link to the index webpage of that server. And the link does not work. However if i just create an html file in my system and add the same link it works.

Comment: Ah. Servers can't serve local pages like that because of security. Static html files can.

Comment: @DavidPostill What security issue would there be from that? As user i can just copy the link anyway and open in my browser. So it would seem safe for a server to link there: if the file exists in users computer, then browser would open it.

Comment: If the server was on the internet it would be trying to open a file on the local machine not on the server machine.

Comment: @DavidPostill i fail to understand how that would be a security issue. From my naive understanding, clicking a link simply changes the current page the browser is viewing. How would redirecting to a file in the user's local machine (that could even not exist) cause a security issue?

Comment: What if it was a file containing passwords or other sensitive information? You have just sent that information to some random website ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes that would be bad. But how would the website get access to that file just from redirecting to it? If i am in a website and then type `file:///<somefile>` in browser url (and then press return) would the current website get access to it?

Comment: [http - Why do browsers disallow accessing files from local file system even if the HTML document is also on the local file system? - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html)